# dlib fails on raspbian

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dlib

I'm trying to install `dlib` on my raspbian and I am having a lot of problems. Well this is not real at all beacuse theoretically it's installed.

I have a virtual environment and it's installed with opencv-python, when i am in this virtual environment and I execute python if I write `import dlib` there is no problem. But if I run a `.py` file previously writted says the error

> import dlib
>
> ImportError: No module named 'dlib'

Why this is happening? I've been thinking maybe there is a conflict of versions, python2 or python3, but I don't know. In this case I'm using python 3.5.

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf done!

Comment: My guess is your RAM is getting full, make sure you have some swap space.